# Is there something like WPF commands in Oxygene?

Tags: wpf, command, oxygene

I'm just getting started with Oxygene.

I'm trying to make a litlle WPF project with a MVVM pattern.
So far it's working but i can't find a way to implement commands in oxygene.

Does anyone know if this can be done and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a static class in the same project as the form is.
like this:

```
Command = public static class 
  public
    SomeCommand: RoutedCommand := new RoutedCommand();
end;
```

Then you need to create a XAML name space alias (in the XAML of your form):

```
xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:YourProjectNameSpace"
```

Suppose you have a button on the form and you want to hook it up to the command:

```
 <Button Content="Some Button" Command="{x:Static Local:Command.SomeCommand}" />
```

The next step is to setup what the command should be doing...
In my case I just hooked up a lambda expression but you can use the MVVM pattern to delegate this behaviour to somewhere else.

I did this in the load of the form:

```
self.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Command.SomeCommand, (ss,ee) -> 
begin
  //Do Stuff
  //Do some more stuff
end));
```